# How to label a column based on the value on other data frame, but only for that column (Read description)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two similar table like:
Table 1:

| SKU | Status | Sellout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Discontinue | 20 |
| DEF | PSKU | 30 |

Table 2:

| SKU | Status | Branch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  | Jv |
| DEF |  | Db |

So the difference is, in the 2nd table the Status value is NaN. I want to make the status in Table 2 the same with Table 1, but only if the label on Status column is "Discontinue".

So after processing, Table 2 should look like this:

| SKU | Status | Branch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Discontinue | Jv |
| DEF |  | Db |

If I use merge, it will add 'Sellout' column from table 1 to table 2, and I don't want that to happen. Any advice will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) `Table 2` in this case `df1` with `Table 1` in this case `df` after dropping rows on `Table 1` that do not contain the requisite `Status`

```
df1.update(df.where(df['Status']=='Discontinue').dropna())


print(df1)
```

Outcome

```
   SKU       Status Branch
0  ABC  Discontinue     Jv
1  DEF                  Db
```